# How to Calculate PV$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos ax}{x^4-1}\:dx\: $for all a in R

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

Can anyone help calculate this integral?

$$\text{PV}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos ax}{x^4-1}\,dx$$

for  all  $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: If you add more context, you might get more informative answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you begin, first note that

$$\frac{1}{x^4-1}=\frac{1/2}{x^2-1}-\frac{1/2}{x^2+1}$$

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^4-1}\,dx&=\frac12\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^4-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 \text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2-1}\,dx-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\,dx
\end{align}$$

To finish, write $\cos(ax)=\text{Re}(e^{i|a|x})$, and close the real line contours in the upper half-plane, deform the contour around the singularities around $z=\pm 1$ of the first integral on the right-hand side, and apply the reside theorem to the second integral to account for the poles at $z=\pm i$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: (+1) Is the final outcome $-\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sin|a|+e^{-|a|}\right)$ ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: that is twice the final outcome. Partial fractions do not simplify the contour integration. At least when I did it, I just used the denominator $z^4-1$ and avoided the second integral.

Comment: @robjohn: agreed, I dropped a $2$ factor, fine.

Comment: @robjohn You're right.  The PFE was unnecessary.  My intent was to isolate the poles on the real axis from those in the imaginary axis to highlight the distinct approaches of evaluating the resulting integrals (the first requiring deformation around the poles without enclosed poles, and the second a direct application of the residue theorem).  This was for pedagogical reason only.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Here is a contour that might prove useful

[image]